# Flash Professional vs FlashBuilder 4.6 for mobile app development

Tags: android, flash, ios

From the marketing materials I see online, it seems to me that FlashBuilder 4.6 is a subset of the functionality available in Flash Professional.  If I understand correctly, mobile app development target iOS and Android started as a plugin for Flash Pro and has since been made a separate product.

But can Flash Pro still do all the multi-platform targeting that FlashBuilder 4.6 can do?  What other considerations are there between the two applications that are critical to understand for mobile app development?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adobe pulled mobile support from Flash, so Flash Professional would not work for mobile development; however, I believe you can use Adobe AIR to package Flash for mobile. As for which is better for mobile development, it is easier to test mobile applications with Flash Builder.

Other than that, it just depends what you are trying to do. Flash Professional is good for animations. Flash Builder is better for code-heavy projects. I assume you are planning on making games, so Flash Builder would be best.

Comment: Just to add on, this 'Adobe AIR' is not a separate product. Flash Professional, FlashBuilder, and even the free FlashDevelop can export to Adobe AIR. It's just a matter of configuration during the export process. You can use AIR to unlock more functionality on desktop Flash .swfs, or create mobile applications.